Whats the difference between the term "open" growth and inderterminate growth in plants?
My textbook has a paragraph whose heading itself is

"Plant Growth Generally is Indeterminate"

and in that paragraph it says

The cells of such meristems
have the capacity to divide and self-perpetuate. The product, however,
soon loses the capacity to divide and such cells make up the plant body.
This form of growth wherein new cells are always being added to the
plant body by the activity of the meristem is called the open form of growth

and thats it! in the entire chapter it doesent bother to speak about these terms....so would be great if anyone helped...

Which text book is this?

I think 'open growth' and 'indeterminate growth' are synonymous in this context. The opposite of 'indeterminate growth' is 'determinate growth'. 'Determinate growth' refers to when a plant ceases growth after reaching a certain size or number of cells, and 'indeterminate growth' is when a plant could continue to grow indefinitely until in runs into resource/space/physiological constraints.

i dont know how to reply to a comment but @-M_ this is a school textbook in India called the NCERT https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kebo113.pdf a link to this particular chapter its on 2nd page. and @Eonema thanks for the help
